# Trapezoidal and rectangle rule for double integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Tell me please, how to use trapezoidal and middle rectangles rules to calculate double integral without dividing the integration interval ($n=1$).

$$
\int_1^4\int_1^4 (x^3 + y^2)~{\rm d}x{\rm d}y
$$

I tried to use the trapezoidal rule in this way:

$$
\int_1^4\int_1^4 (x^3 + y^2)~{\rm d}x{\rm d}y = \frac{f(1,1) + f(1,4) + f(4,1) + f(4,4)}{2}(4-1)(4-1) = 729
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I add my example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just apply the method to each integral, for example, for the trapezoidal rule

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_1^4 \color{blue}{\left(\int_1^4f(x,y){\rm d}x\right)}{\rm d}y &=&
\int_1^4 \color{blue}{\left(\frac{4-1}{2}[f(1,y) + f(4,y)]\right)}{\rm d}y \\
&=& \frac{3}{2}\left\{ \color{red}{\int_1^4f(1,y){\rm d}y} + \color{orange}{\int_1^4f(4,y){\rm d}y}\right\} \\
&=& \frac{3}{2}\left\{\color{red}{\frac{4-1}{2}[f(1,1) + f(1,4)]} + \color{orange}{\frac{4-1}{2}[f(4,1) + f(4,4)]} \right\} \\
&=& \frac{9}{4}\left[ f(1,1) + f(1,4) + f(4,1) + f(4,4)\right]
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

You need to divide by $4$ to get the average height of the points, instead of dividing by $2$.

Everything else you did was correct.